# Three words into my title and I'm seeing a "appears subjective" popup

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I typed the following three words in the title of a question:

"Correcting your schema"

and got the blue "appears subjective" popup.  I'm not seeing anything subjective about this title.

I tinkered with my title a bit and found that what is being objected to is the word "your".  I can enter

"correcting a db schema"

and not draw a pop-up.  The use of "your" here doesn't seem subjective.  Also, isn't three words into the title a bit early to start drawing conclusions about the post?

BTW, my question isn't posted yet.

Comment: That's quiet specific for the stackexchange side of things, not really something we can configure for our site. Maybe better asked at http://meta.stackexchange.com/ where more stackexchange mods and developers are active.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Asking here is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title warning is a relatively simple regex that for the most part gets the job done. It's there to warn folks who might otherwise write up a question along the lines of "what's your favorite X?" which doesn't tend to work out too well on most SE sites.

You found an edge case where it doesn't *quite* apply, but that's okay - it's just an informational warning that doesn't prevent you from posting. If anything, it made you come up with a marginally more descriptive title... seems like it served a purpose.

Comment: I realized that the message was just a warning, but having it appear after typing three words in the title felt, well, a bit hasty.